# 500 error response when GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/devices

Tags: api, graph, beta

I am trying to reach the list of user devices with a GET here:

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/devices

I am using the Graph Explorer at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

I get a 500 error response.

In addition to the Graph Explorer, I also tried making the HTTP request manually using a token for a demo tenant, for a user that has at least 1 registered device. Same result.

Any ideas what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

In case you have network virtual appliances (NVA) such as firewall to inspect the network traffic, ensure that the required ports are allowed.
Also in case the traffic is force tunneled, ensure that the UDR routes for control plane ip addresses and others are added. Virtual network gateway route propagation settings should also be properly set up. Else, you might have asymmetric routing issues.

Comment: There are no network restrictions. Also, as I stated in the question, the same occurs when I use the Graph Explorer.